# Robocopy from corrupted SD Card hangs on some files despite /R:0 /W:0. Manually adding each to /XF list and reruning is too slow. How can I automate?

Tags: data-recovery, sd-card, robocopy

I'm trying to recover thousands of photos and videos from a corrupted SD Card.

I've tried to recover the SD Card with chkdsk /F /R /X . Here is the relevant output:

> "Corruption was found while examining the volume bitmap."
> ...
> The disk does not have enough space to replace bad clusters
> detected in file \FOUND.000\FILE0082.CHK of name 76599.
> Corruption was found while examining files in directory \FOUND.000\ (246).
> 100 percent completed....
> File and folder verification is complete.
> ...
> Free space verification is complete.
> Windows has made corrections to the file system.
> No further action is required.

Now I'm using Robocopy with the /R:0 and /W:0 options to recover files. It successfully moves a large percentage of files. In some cases it detects an error (always the same error, different files) and moves quickly on, e.g.:

> ```
>   New File           1.5 m    20230213_133228.jpg
> ```
>
> 2024/01/25 10:23:05 ERROR 23 (0x00000017) Copying File G:\DCIM\Camera\20230213_133228.jpg
> Data error (cyclic redundancy check).

In other cases it just completely hangs on some files, e.g.:

> ```
>   New File           1.8 m    20230213_151953.jpg
> ```
>
> 13%
> 26%

I've even left it overnight to see if it just takes ages but there was no progress at all. Interrupting with Ctrl-Break also takes ages or doesn't seem to stop it at all, in which case removing the SD Card (which is in a simple USB SD Card reader) is a janky solution but does finally interrupt the job.

I then manually add the problematic files to an exclude files list in the Robocopy job file and rerun. The next n files, from just a few to over a hundred, are copied before it hangs again.

This is very tedious and time consuming!

- Is there any way to set a timeout and then skip the files on which
  robocopy hangs or automatically append them to the exclude files list
  and restart?
- Are there any other solutions?

I've also tried TeraCopy but that hangs too.

- Any other recommendations for a robust file copier that will not hang
  on corrupt files?

Answer (score 0):

I use Beyond Compare for copying.  Its interactive but continues with the next file if there is an error on the current one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Rohit. I've just tried the file copying functionality (presumably I have to sync the source and destination directories) but unfortunately Beyond Compare hangs already when I try to navigate to / select the source directory. :-(

Comment: After managing to restart BC I tried adding the source directory path manually and the sync started. However it hit a Cyclic Redundancy Check (same error as Robocopy finds and skips) and is unable to copy the first file. It then stops. I can neither stop nor pause and resume the operation. I'm new to Stack Exchange / SuperUser and havent't worked out how to add a screenshot here yet!

Comment: @anglosachsen you add photos to your question, nowhere else ... edit your question and then click the button with the mountains and moon